python requests.response not working for V6 swap API (solana python exchane)
I am trying to swap solana using python, i decided to use V6 swap api,
I followed instructions, and this is my code
import requests
import json


url = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112&outputMint=EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v&amount=1000000000"

payload = {}
headers = {    
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}

quote = json.loads(requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload).text)

url = "https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap"


payload = json.dumps({
  "userPublicKey": "myPublicAddress",
  "wrapAndUnwrapSol": True,
  "useSharedAccounts": True,
  "feeAccount": "",
  "computeUnitPriceMicroLamports": 0,
  "prioritizationFeeLamports": 0,
  "asLegacyTransaction": False,
  "useTokenLedger": False,
  "destinationTokenAccount": "",
  "dynamicComputeUnitLimit": True,
  "skipUserAccountsRpcCalls": True,
  "quoteResponse": quote
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)

I am always getting back response like:
{"error":"Parse error: WrongSize at line 1 column 1479"}
i tried everything, it always says it has error on new column

FYI, you can use response.json instead of json.loads(response.text)

The GET request shouldn't have any payload.

You can use json=<dictionary> instead of calling json.dumps(<dictionary>)

here is the official documentation i have been following: https://station.jup.ag/api-v6/post-swap

Try leaving out the empty feeAccount and destinationTokenAccount.

Documentation of feeAccount says "only pass in if you set a feeBps and make sure that the feeAccount has been created"

i left feeAccount and destinationTokenAccount on "", do you mean delete it compleatly from that list?

Sorry, I don't understand that.

sorry, a lot of typos, please try reading it again

I meant to leave it out completely.

when i left out fee account, destinationTokenAccount, and computeUnitPriceMicroLamports it worked... thanks!
